# jquery css Smooth scroll between sections with different backgrounds

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do smooth scroll between parts of my page. Basicly my aim is to have similar effect like here: http://diablomedia.com/
So far: I have the menu, different backgrounds, i'm able to navigate, got smooth scroll from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/ but the background is problem... it's just... not smooth, I can't explaint it more clearly so I just paste some of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>xxx</title>

<style type="text/css">
html {
    background: #1d1d1d;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 10px normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #1d1d1d;
}

h1 {
    font: 4.7em normal Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

h1 small {
    font: 0.2em normal Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.4em;
    display: block;
    color: #ccc;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    background: rgba(29, 29, 29, 0.85);
    z-index: 100;
}

.main_content1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://www.mega-tapety.info/resize/sztuka-tapety3d-1600-1200-3422.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

.main_content2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://www.tapety.nja.pl/images/wallpapers/26335506/Widoki/Niebo/17.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://i.pinger.pl/pgr496/a03b8c70001f8f5d490da42f/pobrano-z-tapety.pinger.pl-29.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content4 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://www.mega-tapety.info/wallpapers/krajobrazy/morzairzeki/390_4500_3.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://i.pinger.pl/pgr448/ca9845940015a295490d848a/pobrano-z-tapety.pinger.pl-1D.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content6 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://i.pinger.pl/pgr188/5b715190002669eb490d8488/pobrano-z-tapety.pinger.pl-1C.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content7 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background: url("http://skkf.net/pulpity/7tapeta.jpg") no-repeat fixed
        50% 0 #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
}

.main_content8 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    background:
        url("http://zdjecia-fotografia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/tapety-na-pulpit-samochody3.jpg")
        no-repeat fixed 50% 0 #FFFFFF;
}

.text_container {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

img {
    border: none;
}

ul#topnav {
    margin: 0 0 0 18%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#topnav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
}

ul#topnav a,ul#topnav span {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    clear: both;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

ul#topnav a {
    color: #7bc441;
}

ul#topnav span {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
            .ready(
                    function() {

                        $("#topnav li").prepend("<span></span>"); //Throws an empty span tag right before the a tag

                        $("#topnav li").each(function() { //For each list item...
                            var linkText = $(this).find("a").html(); //Find the text inside of the a tag
                            $(this).find("span").show().html(linkText); //Add the text in the span tag
                        });

                        $("#topnav li").hover(function() { //On hover...
                            $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
                                marginTop : "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels
                            }, 250);
                        }, function() { //On hover out...
                            $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
                                marginTop : "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px)
                            }, 250);
                        });

                        function filterPath(string) {
                            return string.replace(/^\//, '').replace(
                                    /(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
                                    .replace(/\/$/, '');
                        }
                        var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
                        var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

                        $('a[href*=#]')
                                .each(
                                        function() {
                                            var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname)
                                                    || locationPath;
                                            if (locationPath == thisPath
                                                    && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
                                                    && this.hash.replace(/#/,
                                                            '')) {
                                                var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
                                                if (target) {
                                                    var targetOffset = $target
                                                            .offset().top;
                                                    $(this)
                                                            .click(
                                                                    function(
                                                                            event) {
                                                                        event
                                                                                .preventDefault();
                                                                        $(
                                                                                scrollElem)
                                                                                .animate(
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            scrollTop : targetOffset
                                                                                        },
                                                                                        1000,
                                                                                        function() {
                                                                                            location.hash = target;
                                                                                        });
                                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                        // use the first element that is "scrollable"
                        function scrollableElement(els) {
                            for ( var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i < argLength; i++) {
                                var el = arguments[i], $scrollElement = $(el);
                                if ($scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0) {
                                    return el;
                                } else {
                                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                                    var isScrollable = $scrollElement
                                            .scrollTop() > 0;
                                    $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                                    if (isScrollable) {
                                        return el;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            return [];
                        }
                    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <h1>
            <small>Navatar.pl</small>
        </h1>
        <br />
        <ul id="topnav">
            <li><a href="#1">Dojedź szybciej</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#2">mCB</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#3">Pogadaj ze znajomymi</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#4">Check-in</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#5">Xplore</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#6">About</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#7">Cos</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#8">Jeszcze</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="main_content1" id="1"></div>
    <div class="main_content2" id="2"></div>
    <div class="main_content3" id="3"></div>
    <div class="main_content4" id="4"></div>
    <div class="main_content5" id="5"></div>
    <div class="main_content6" id="6"></div>
    <div class="main_content7" id="7"></div>
    <div class="main_content8" id="8"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know it looks awful but I'm still learning :)

Comment: i took the liberty to add your code into jsfiddle (feel free to add it to your question)  http://jsfiddle.net/YJXrX/
can you explain what exactly does not run like you want it? i have a feeling these processor heavy animations might be the issue, and it just doesn't look as pretty as you want it on different machines / browsers

Comment: ok, i get it, but can you tell me exactly what you want changed... here on my system, rather fast laptop, with windows 7 and using chrome to test, seems to work very smoothe

what exactly is your problem with your solution you have?

Comment: well the thing is: open my page, and diablo media page... when you scroll down mine, one background is covered with another, while on their site one background, let say, moves up insted of being covered

Comment: or more clearly: on my page click "Pogadaj ze znajomym", there's a horse on the bottom right? when you scroll down it's slowly covered with another background istead i'd like it to be "move up" by the beach theme from bottom

Comment: hm ah you really want to change the effect, i thought it was about the smoothe transitions or anything, well sorry can't tell you what to do exactly, i would need to disect the code you use and for that i need more time... if i have some time i will take a look at this but for now I am afraid I won't be of mutch help

Comment: take your time, i appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> well the thing is: open my page, and diablo media page... when you
>   scroll down mine, one background is covered with another, while on
>   their site one background, let say, moves up insted of being covered

This is because diablomedia.com is using a parallax scrolling effect which allows the different backgrounds to scroll at different speeds, giving it the illusion you are talking about.

Here is a link to a tutorial and more information about this parallax scrolling technique: [One page website, vertical parallax](http://www.webdesignshock.com/one-page-website/)

I hope this is more of what you were looking for.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for :) I consider implementing it to my page